# Is there an existing validation rule that works on the sum of several properties, where the sum is not a property?

Tags: c#, .net, api, fluentvalidation

Let's say we have a request object :

```
public class ExampleRequest {
    public int? A { get; set; }
    public int? B { get; set; }
    public int? C { get; set; }
    public int? D { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and there exists an API rule where 1 ≤ Sum(a, b, c, d) ≤ 10.

- Sum(a, b, c, d) must be at least 1 and at most 10.

I've tried implementing this rule like so:

```
RuleFor(x => x.A ?? 0 + x.B ?? 0 + x.C ?? 0 + x.D ?? 0)
    .GreaterThan(0)
    .LessThanOrEqualTo(10);
```

This rule didn't work.

a) How can I craft a ruleset to handle this kind of scenario?

b) Is it even possible to create a rule in this case-- where the rule isn't necessarily applied to a property of the object, but rather some function applied to several properties?

Edit: Edited code blocks to represent the cause of the error.

Comment: What error are you getting? Because I just tested your validator and it works

Comment: That's the problem, I'm not getting an error. The API is accepting the request and giving me a 200 response code. It should be denying the request and giving me back a 400 response code with an error.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are validating the instance? `var result = validator.Validate(myInstance);` this result is returning true when it shouldn't?

Comment: Hey Magnetron, 
1) I never call that function because FluentValidation is applied automatically to the request object.

2) I removed the coalesce operators inside the lambda function because you said that it works for you and now its working. I don't know why that fixed it but it did lol

Comment: Style Side note: the C# convention is to use CamelCase for classes, properties and methods names, so you should use `ExampleRequest`, `A`, `B`, `C`  and `D` for your names.

Comment: When I wrote the question I forgot that the class uses int? (nullable int) incase there are null values in the database and Visual Studio IDE recommend me to use coalesce in the rule. I updated the original question to show this. For some reason the coalesce operators make this rule not work. I don't know why...

Comment: Thank you for your help! @Magnetron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is because [Operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence). `+` has higher precedence than `??`. This should work:

```
RuleFor(x => (x.a ?? 0) + (x.b ?? 0) + (x.c ?? 0) + (x.d ?? 0) )
            .GreaterThan(0)
            .LessThanOrEqualTo(10);
```